# Spring boot -- Postman : Making a POST request with foreign

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, postman

I am trying to make a post request using POSTMAN with Spring Boot.
When making a POST with foreign key, is returning null

- Relation between User and Role is (ManyToOne).
- Relation between User and Centre is (ManyToOne).

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String login;
  private String password;
  private String nom;
  private String prenom;
  private String telephone;
  private String email;
  @Column(name = "idccms")
  private String idCCMS;
  private String matricule;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "Code_Role")
  private Role role;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "Code_Centre")
  private Centre centre;
  ```

POSTMAN INPUT:

[image]

POSTMAN OUTPUT:

[image]

My method :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public Utilisateur save(@RequestBody Utilisateur user) {
    return userRepo.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json input should match your field names, not the name of the column in the database. So use role and centre in the json input. Also make sure to have setters. Same for the idCCms.

Or another solution could be to define those names with a @JsonProperty("Code_Role") above the field.